# Erro md5 ao renomear array de upload arquivo php

Tags: php, md5, multiple-file-upload

Tenho o seguinte código que faz upload de vários arquivos:

```
<?php


if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors = array();

    foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];        
        $file_parts = pathinfo($file_name);     
        $extensions = array("jpeg","jpg","png");            

    if(in_array ($file_parts['extension'],$extensions)){

        //renomea o arquivo 
        $file_parts = ".".$file_parts['extension'];
        $file_name = time().uniqid(md5()).$file_parts;

        if($file_size > 2097152){

            $errors[] = 'Tamanho do arquivo de ser menor que 2MB';

        }//if($file_size > 2097152){        

            if(empty($errors)==true){

            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "user_data/".$file_name); 

            }else{
                print_r($errors); 
            }//if(empty($errors)==true){

        }else{

            $errors [] = 'Extensão não permitida';

        }//if(in_array ($file_parts['extension'],$extensions))

    if(empty($errors)){

        print_r("<br/>".$file_name."<br/>");
        echo "Sucesso";

    }//if(empty($errors))

    }//foreach ($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)


}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Ele está fazendo o upload dos arquivo normalmente e renomeando, estão com todos arquivo na pasta e renomeados, mas ele apresenta o seguinte erro quando faço o upload:

**Warning: md5() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload\index.php on line 17**

147293915357cb449171b91.jpg

Sucesso

**Warning: md5() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload\index.php on line 17**

147293915357cb449171f7a.jpg

Sucesso

**Warning: md5() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\upload\index.php on line 17**

147293915357cb449172362.jpg

Sucesso

Alguém tem uma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: A função `md5()` espera alguma coisa para encriptar. Insira os critérios  `datetime` que esta usando dentro da função.

Comment: Obrigado @WilliamNovak era isso mesmo, fiz o seguinte `$file_name = uniqid(md5(time())).$file_parts;`

Comment: Eu vejo bastante caso onde a pessoa renomeia imagens pra MD5. Deve ter algum blog ou tutorialmeio maluco ensinando isso em algum lugar. Seja lá onde for, sugiro não levar a sério, pois não é vantagem nenhuma. Quaisquer ganhos que você possa imaginar, são conseguidos com soluções mais simples e com menos riscos. Muito melhor seria, por exemplo, usar uma simples numeração sequencial ou um uniqid(), que não tem risco nenhum de colisão. E nos casos onde for armazenar algum dado em DB, o próprio ID da coluna já serve como referencia única.

Comment: Estava lendo sobre isso e pessoal estava falando para colocar o MD5, mas realmente não é uma boa opção colocar ele. Obrigado pela dica @Bacco.

Comment: Aliás, fui pegar o link do uniqid() pra você: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.uniqid.php e me deparei com uma coisa engraçada. O site do PHP usa um MD5 de uniqid(), o que é péssimo. Mas nos próprios comentários da página teve usuário explicando que é ruim, e propondo alternativa melhor. De qq forma, para nome de arquivo, o uniqid() funciona bem. E como ele é baseado no relógio, nunca repete. Fica um pouco maior o nome do arquivo, mas garante o sossego quanto a colisões.

Comment: Agora, quando for usar DB, lembre-se que o ID da coluna é a melhor coisa para o nome da imagem. Se quiser "encurtar" ele, pode usar hexadecimal, ou mesmo base64 (com caracteres adequados para URL). Nota: base64 é outra coisa que é raro ser bem usado, a única finalidade dele é representar bytes num conjunto mais limitado de caracteres. Não é pra usar para armazenar informação em arquivo, muito menos no lugar de "criptografia" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como [já comentado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/150906/#comment311573_150906) pelo William, faltou dizer do que é que você está gerando o `md5()`.

Como de qualquer forma, neste seu caso o `md5` não é de grande utilidade, uma possível solução é essa:

```
$file_name = uniqid().base_convert(mt_rand(),10,36).$file_parts;
```

Se preferir inverter, essas duas sintaxes dão na mesma:

```
$file_name = uniqid(base_convert(mt_rand(),10,36)).$file_parts;
$file_name = base_convert(mt_rand(),10,36).uniqid().$file_parts;
```

Para quase todos os casos, o mais elegante é simplesmente isso:

```
$file_name = uniqid().$file_parts;
```

mas como você processa vários arquivos, tem essas considerações:

- o `uniqid()` já é a codificação de tempo do sistema em uma forma um pouco mais compacta, então não faz sentido concatenar com `time()`;
- normalmente o `uniqid()` nunca vai se repetir por ser baseado no relógio + data + microsegundos, mas se for um caso onde você tem um loop, e vai processar várias coisas praticamente ao mesmo tempo, o `base_convert(mt_rand())` acrescenta um componente aleatorizador extra;
- `md5(uniqid())` é uma coisa comum de se ver, e está até no manual do PHP, mas é um absurdo num código real. O `md5()` de fato reduz a qualidade do `uniqid()` e dá margem para colisões;

Agora, se você for usar isso em situações que vá indexar imagens no DB, fica mais elegante pegar o ID da coluna, com algo como o `mysqli_insert_id`, e gerar o nome baseado nisso:

```
$id = mysqli_insert_id( $con );
$file_name = base_convert( $id, 10, 36 ).$file_parts;
```

Em todos os casos, estamos usando o `base_convert` basicamente para encurtar valores numéricos. Usei base 36 por ser o máximo que o PHP aceita nestes casos.

Eu preferiria base64, mas o PHP só converte strings para b64, e não números, sendo menos vantajoso nesse caso (tratar números como string ocuparia mais espaço, em vez de economizar).

Manual:

> http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.base-convert.php